# How to log scale y axis on bar chart when data.frame reads as non-numeric? R

Tags: r, plot, character, bar-chart, numeric

I am having issues with the argument `log = "y"` from `barplot()`

```
        ADR BCLREQ CALL  BOND FUT     CD   CDS CDX 
IO Only    "0"   "3"         "0"      "0"  "0" "1" 
IO and TS  "0"   "0"         "0"      "0"  "0" "0" 
No Changes "5"   "45"        "9"      "39" "2" "11"
TS Only    "0"   "0"         "0"      "0"  "0" "0" 
Freq       "5"   "48"        "9"      "39" "2" "12".
```

.

```
 > dput(data)
structure(c("0", "0", "5", "0", "5", "3", "0", "45", "0", "48", 
"0", "0", "9", "0", "9", "0", "0", "39", "0", "39", "0", "0", 
"2", "0", "2", "1", "0", "11", "0", "12"), .Dim = 5:6, .Dimnames = list(
    c("IO Only", "IO and TS", "No Changes", "TS Only", "Freq"
    ), c("ADR", "BCLREQ CALL", "BOND FUT", "CD", "CDS", "CDX"
    )))
```

Now the barplot

```
  BAR2 <- barplot(data[1:4,], main = "Build Efficiency", ylab = "Manual Frequency", 
                              xlab = "IO Screen", beside = F, log = "y",
                              col = c("blue", "green", "red", "yellow"), las = 1, legend.text = rownames(data)[1:4])
```

The above should result in: 
[image]

I would like to make the 'Y' axis in log scale. after adding `log = "y",` I get:

```
Error in height + offset : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

After a bit of digging I realized my data might not be numeric? not sure if checking correctly but:

```
> str(data[1,2])
 chr "3"
```

So I tried:

```
  data <- data.matrix(data, rownames.force = NA)

  data[1:5,] <- sapply(data[1:5,], as.numeric)
```

I still get:

```
Error in height + offset : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Comment: You don't have a data frame, you have a matrix. Turn it into a data frame with `as.data.frame()` and then convert columns to numeric. (Or correct the problem upstream wherever you read this data).

Comment: data <- data.matrix(as.data.frame(data), rownames.force = NA) not working very well.

Comment: If you want a matrix not a data frame a simpler way is `mode(data) = "numeric"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments mentioned, your data is stored as characters. Since `data` is a matrix, use `mode(data) = "numeric"`.

You also have the problem that 0's are in your dataset and you cannot log transform this without a transformation. See this post for some solutions: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/how-should-i-transform-non-negative-data-including-zeros